# The causal relation and relativistic transformation

Tags: special-relativity, causality

We know that order in time between two events with causal relation is invariant under relativistic transformation. Now if order in time between two events is invariant under every relativistic transformation, must there be causal relation between the two events?

**updat** given any two event $p$, and $q$, $ds^2=(x_p-x_q)^2+(y_p-y_q)^2+(z_p-z_q)^2+(ict)^2\leq 0$ and it is invariant that $p$, is before $q$ or simultaneous with  $q$ under relativistic transformation. must there be causal relation between $p$ and $q$ the two events??

Comment: No. Things can be in the past of an event without causing that event.

Comment: @Chris, But we can find a  relativistic transformation which can change the time order  between the two event. So I think they must have causal relation.

Comment: The question can be asked in another way, can any time order between two events without causal relation be changed by some relativistic transformation?

Comment: Causality is distinct from time ordering.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnusa, any example, theory, or experiment to refute  ?